# How to individually synchronize data members

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, synchronized

I have been searching the web for this, but have been unable to find any article that comes close to this, and I'm quite surprised by that. Maybe the wisdom is hidden somewhere that I have yet to find.

Suppose I have a class with 10 members of various types (for the sake of simplicity, let's say they are mixed of ints and Strings), and each one of them has its own accessor methods. Now, I want to make this class thread-safe. But, some of these data members don't necessarily interact with each other. For example the class `Person` below, has `age` and `name` and other properties.

```
public class Person {
    private volatile int age;
    private String name;
    private volatile long blabla;
    // ... and so on

    public synchronized int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public synchronized void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    // .. and so on for each data member
}
```

One thread may only need to read/write `age`, and other threads only need to modify `name`.  Obviously, adding `synchronized` to each and every one of the accessor methods is a bad idea as it locks the entire instance of the object. A thread that's calling `getAge()` has to wait for another thread that's calling `getName()` even though `age` and `name` are two separate fields.

So, one obvious solution is to create a lock for each field (or add `volatile` to primitive types).  However, this seems to be an overkill. If I have 10 data members, do I also need 10 locks?  I'm wondering if there's another way of achieving this without excessive locking.

Comment: No need for `volatile` if your methods are synchronized and the members are private.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are concerned about synchronizing primitive types, this is an excellent use case for AtomicInteger etc...  They are very fast and ensure thread-safety.  For more info:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomicvars.html

Comment: While I agree with Gray that this smells like premature optimization, it's always good to know the atomic variables and how they're used. Very useful for direct, concurrent variable access/modification. +1

Answer (score 4):

First off, if you are talking about primitives (or immutable objects like `String`) then all you should need is to mark each of the fields `volatile`.  Locks won't be necessary if all you are doing is getting and setting field values.

However, if your get/set methods do multiple operations and `synchronized` blocks are need, having a `synchronized` blocks per field seems like premature optimization to me.  I think that `synchronized` methods on a small object like your `Person` is a perfectly appropriate way to accomplish this.  Unless you have real reasons (i.e. profiler output), I would not try to make it more complicated.  *Certainly* a lock per field is overkill in just about any situation.

It would make a difference if the method takes a long time.  Then you would *not* want to lock the entire object and block the other accessors.  Then it is a good time to have multiple locks -- each for separate calculation.  But if your object truly is just trying to protect get/set then a `synchronized` method is fine.

Couple of other comments:

- If you can get away with just `volatile` fields then you don't need any `synchronized` blocks.
- If you have `synchronized` methods then you do not need to make your fields `volatile`.
- If the `name` field should probably be marked as `final` if it is not being written to.

Comment: Does it matter if it is a small/big object? I think not, but I get your point.

Comment: It does not matter @iccthedral.  What _does_ matter is if the method in question takes a long time to do the calculations.  If they are truly get/set methods then the overall size of the object does not matter.